# How to debug missing X-Robots-Tag

Tags: nginx, apache2

In the setup of Apache as webserver and Nginx as reverse proxy developer added zu Apache configuration (htaccess) den X-Robots-Tag mit der noindex-Anweisung für PDF-files, like

```
<Files ~ "\.pdf$">
  Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</Files>
```

The code above comes [from Google, on the very bottom of the page](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag).

**Issue**: Header check shows nor X-Robots-Tag, neither its content.

How is this case to debug?

Comment: Has the header module (mod_headers) been loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the headers module has been loaded.  Look for

```
LoadModule headers_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_headers.so
```

Comment: Thank you! Will do it as first on monday. Can it be a case, that Nginx as reverse proxy, because of any circumstances, doesn't let Apache header rules through?

Comment: When "any circumstances" = nginx has been configured to remove the headers.  NOT by default.   Test: make a request to Apache direct.  Do you get the header?

Comment: BTW,  Apache and Nginx are both reverse proxies.  Having the two is overkill.   Nginx is a very good product, but if you have Apache, there really is no need for Nginx.

Comment: Ok, than to set off Nginx and inspect its config could be helpful too. Thanks, i'll report on monday.